# What is retraction in pronunciation?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, pronunciation

As in:

> [I]n English /t, d, n, l/ are *retracted* before /r/. [*emphasis added*]
>   —*Wikipedia*, “[Allophone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophone#Examples_in_English_vs._other_languages)”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'Retracted' basically means that those consonants are articulated farther back in the mouth, and sometimes referred to as 'backed'. The opposite is 'advanced'.

In the examples you give, try saying *dog* and *drink* while concentrating on the position of the tip of your tongue. In *dog*, it should be on the ridge (the alveolar ridge) behind your top teeth, while for *drink* it goes further back, ready to articulate the /r/.

For a comparison, you could try *cork*, in which the first /k/ is backed and the final one isn't, and then *keen* in which the /k/ is advanced.

If you have trouble feeling the difference, some recommend sticking your fingers in your mouth as you say the word. Personally, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Well put, friend.  Excellent examples.  Also, atrocious, try, unrelenting, Adrian, alright, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that 'retraction' refers to a slightly laterally inferior positioning of the tongue in pronunciation.  The tongue is further backwards of the dental line in the speaking of retracted sounds.